# Why does positioning child as absolute to its relevant parent push it outside of the parent div?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to move the image around inside of the parent div using position absolute on the image and position relative on the parent but when I do so it pushes it outside of the parent div. Below is the html/css

```
<div class="work">
    <h2 class='workHeader'>work</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="aboutProject">
            <h3 class="projectTitle">Peak Choice</h3>
            <p class="projectDescription">
                Peak Choice provides real-time data to make choosing where your next Colorado Ski trip easier.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="projectImageSection">
                <img class='peakChoiceImage' src="/img/peakchoicemockup.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.work {
/*position: absolute;*/
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
.workHeader {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);
    grid-template-areas:
        "c i"
        "c i";
}
.projectImageSection {
    /*background-color:#ABECF0;*/
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/

}
.peakChoiceImage {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 25rem;
}
```

Comment: Position absolute does not restrict the element to the bounds of it's parent. It's only positioned in relation to it's parent. If you tell it to be 10000px to the left...that's where it will be. If it's 25rem wide and the parent is 10rem...it will overflow.

Comment: I think a minimal working demo here would be useful.

Comment: ah thank you Paulie_D, I misunderstood the what the child was relative to

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` is being applied to `.projectImageSection`

set `left: 0;` on `.peakChoiceImage` to move to image to the left of the relative positioned parent.